# WPF if else like greater than and less thanValidation in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to achieve something like this in XAML using data or any other triggers available?

Without using C# or IValueConverters

where costprice is a numericupdown control.
So I was trying to set the maximum property of the control.But I don't have any idea about, How can I give greater than and less than conditions?

If side is Buy then CostPrice must be less than SellPrice. 
If side is Sell then CostPrice must be greater than SellPrice

Tried something like shown below

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Side.Code,ConverterParameter={x:Static i:SideCodes.Buy}, Converter={StaticResource EqualsConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="{Binding Path=Price.Value}"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible without `IValueConverter`

Comment: "Without using C# or IValueConverters", why?

Comment: Avoiding Converters sounds like a misguided idea. The important part would be to develop some sort of RangeToBoolean converter that is not tightly coupled to your business logic but can be reused for ranges in many different circumstances.

Comment: I just asked whether would it be possible to do without converters?

Comment: I believe this logic belogs to ViewModel. In viewmodel you would have three properties, MinPrice, MaxPrice and the ActualPrice. Databinding will be then very easy. The calculation of Min and Max price can be in the properties' getters. Very easy, very transparent

Answer (score 2):

> How can I give greater than and less than conditions?
>
> I just asked whether would it be possible to do without converters?

No, you can't do this in pure XAML because there are no 'less than' or 'greater than' operators defined.

XAML is a *markup* language and not a programming language so you should use a converter.

Or you could add another read-only property to the `Side` object that returns a bool that determines whether the value is actually greater than or smaller than some other property:

```
public bool IsSmaller { get { return Code < Buy; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without C# or converters.
However you can write inline C# code in your xaml using the "QuickConverter" (available on NuGet). 
If you're interested : [QuickConverter tutorial](http://blog.danskingdom.com/dont-write-wpf-converters-write-c-inline-in-your-xaml-instead-using-quickconverter/)